# Python - Determinar cuántos elementos se pueden eliminar, y que la lista se encuentre balaceada (pares e impares sumen igual)

Tags: python, funciones

Se tiene una lista `[2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6 , 4, 5, 8, 5, 6, 8, 3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 6]`. Determinar cuántos elementos se pueden eliminar, y que la lista se encuentre balanceada. Que esté balanceada significa que la suma de los índices pares sea igual a los impares.

Por ejemplo:

En la lista = `[5, 5, 2, 5, 8]`. Si se elimina cualquiera de los primeros 5 quedaría `[5,2,5,8]` donde la suma de índices pares e impares es 10. No hay otro elemento que cumple la propiedad de estar balanceado.
Respuesta: 2

Yo he intentado esto. De momento ya se que las sumas no son iguales, y la de los pares es mayor.

```
x = [2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6 , 4, 5, 8, 5, 6, 8, 3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 6]

suma_pares = sum([n for n in x if n % 2 == 0])
suma_impares = sum([n for n in x if not n % 2 == 0])

mayor = 'pares' if suma_pares > suma_impares else \
        'impares' if suma_impares > suma_pares else \
        None

if mayor:
  print('La suma mayor es la de los números: ', mayor)
else:
  print('Los pares e impares suman lo mismo')

  print('Suma pares: ', suma_pares)
  print('Suma impares: ', suma_impares)
```

Output: La suma mayor es la de los números:  pares

Comment: @gcoronel99 esperaba que el resultado sea como en el ejemplo, el output no deberia ser si con impares o pares la suma mayor. Sino, cuántos elementos de la lista debo eliminar para llegar a que sumen igual.

Answer (score 1):

```
# declaracion de variables
lista = [2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6 , 4, 5, 8, 5, 6, 8, 3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 6]
pares = []
impares = []
cont = 0
suma_pares = 0
suma_impares = 0

tamaño_inicial = len(lista)

while len(lista) != 1: # se recorre la lista hasta que quede un solo elemento
    for elemento in lista: # se recorre la lista 
        # se calcula el resto de la civision para determinar si el numero es par o impar
        if elemento %2 ==0:
            pares.append(elemento) # se almacenan los pares para su comparacion
            if cont == 0: 
                suma_pares+=elemento # se almacenan la suma del total de numeros pares de la primera lista que se ingreso
        else:
            impares.append(elemento)# se almacenan los impares para su comparacion
            if cont == 0:
                suma_impares+=elemento # se almacenan la suma del total de numeros impares de la primera lista que se ingreso
        if sum(pares) == sum(impares): # si la suma da exactamente igual se muestra en pantalla
            total = []
            for i in pares:
                total.append(i)
            for i in impares:
                total.append(i)
            print('suma de pares y impares es igual : ',total,' se quitaron ',tamaño_inicial-len(total),' elementos')
    # se le quita un elemento a la lista y se restablecen las variables para volver a interar la nueva lista
    lista.remove(lista[0])
    cont = 1
    pares = []
    impares = []

print('la suma de los numeros pares fue de ',suma_pares)
print('la suma de los números impares fue de ',suma_impares)
```

logrando esta salida:

```
suma de pares y impares es igual :  [6, 4, 5, 5]  se quitaron  14  elementos
suma de pares y impares es igual :  [8, 3, 5]  se quitaron  15  elementos
la suma de los numeros pares fue de  78
la suma de los números impares fue de  23
```

Comment: ahí esta el código con los respectivos comentarios

Comment: Pienso que debes de dar una explicación más amplia con texto de verdad, no solo basta con comentar el código y esperar a que al OP le funcione. También hace falta decir por qué se obtiene el problema y justificar por qué tu solución es válida. **Es solo una recomendación,**  saludos.

Comment: Hola @agustindamore gracias por responder!, consulta:
aun me queda la duda sobre siguiendo el ejemplo ¿cuantos elementos es posible eliminar para poder llegar a esas listas?

Comment: Si ejecuta el código vas a ver qué 2 veces se muestra que la suma de pares y impares es la misma. Con un Len se calcularía la cantidad de números iniciales en la lista y con otro Len cuántos números quedaron la resta de estos dos Len es la cantidad de números que se sacaron

Comment: coronel 99 muchas gracias porlos comentar prometo mejorar en ese apartado. Es la primera vez que aporto una solución !

Comment: @SofiaC por favor revisa la salída y fíjate si es la esperada o falta algun otro detalle?

Comment: @agustindamore gracias por todo, un exito!

Comment: @SofiaC me harías el favor de seleccionar el tick de mi código para que figure como que ya fue solucionado la pregunta. desde ya muchas gracias y estamos en contacto!

Answer (score 1):

Este código busca todas las listas balanceadas que se obtienen con la eliminación de un sólo elemento de la lista original. No es una solución que busque todas las posibles sublistas balanceadas.

En el código original

```
suma_pares = sum([n for n in x if n % 2 == 0])
```

esta sumando los valores pares de la lista, sin importar en que ubicación (par o impar) se encuentren. Sin embargo, la pregunta habla de indices, por lo que la expresión adecuada sería

```
suma_pares = sum([x[n] for n in range(len(x)) if n % 2 == 0])
```

Mejor aún, nos podemos evitar la división partiendo de cero o uno e incrementando en dos cada vez:

```
suma_pares = sum([x[n] for n in range(0, len(x), 2)])
```

La función `calcular` determina si la lista está balanceada a no:

```
def calcular(lista):
    """ Calcular si elementos pares e impares están balanceados

    @param lista: Una lista de valores.
    @return: True si las sumas pares/impares son iguales.
    """
    largo = len(lista)
    suma_pares = sum([lista[n] for n in range(0, largo, 2)])
    suma_impares = sum([lista[n] for n in range(1, largo, 2)])
    return suma_pares == suma_impares
```

La función balancear busca listas balanceadas eliminando un item en secuencia de la lista original:

```
def balancear(lista):
    """ Produce todas las sublistas balanceadas

    @param lista: Lista a balancear
    """
    if calcular(lista):
        print("Lista balanceada {lista}")

    largo = len(lista)
    for i in range(largo - 1):
        copia = lista[:i] + lista[i+1:]
        if calcular(copia):
            print(f"Eliminar indice {i}: {copia}")
```

El programa de prueba

```
x = [2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6 , 4, 5, 8, 5, 6, 8, 3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 6]
y = [5, 5, 2, 5, 8]

print(f"Balancear {y}")
balancear(y)
print()
print(f"Balancear {x}")
balancear(x)
```

produce

```
Balancear [5, 5, 2, 5, 8]
Eliminar indice 0: [5, 2, 5, 8]
Eliminar indice 1: [5, 2, 5, 8]

Balancear [2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 8, 5, 6, 8, 3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 6]
Eliminar indice 9: [2, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 8, 6, 8, 3, 5, 10, 4, 8, 6]
```